# Is a bloom filter with only one input hash still a bloom filter?

Tags: bloom-filter

If I implement a bloom filter where only one hashing algorithm is used (e.g. murmur), is this still considered a bloom filter?

For example, if `a` hashes to `5`, then bit 5 of the filter will be set. If `b` hashes to `1`, then bit 1 of the filter will be set, and so on...

For something to be considered a bloom filter, do at least two bits in the filter have to be set? If only one bit is set, is it called something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still a Bloom filter: one with `k=1`. Depending on the bits per element, it is probably not be the most space-saving one. But there are various reasons why one might pick a `k` that is not `round(bitsPerKey * log(2))`, the main ones are:

- To be able to better compress: here a Bloom filter with `k=1` is best. See also the paper ["Compressed Bloom Filters"](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Emichaelm/NEWWORK/postscripts/cbf2.pdf) from Michael Mitzenmacher.
- To speed up lookup and update: using a lower `k` is faster.

By the way, you can still pick `k` to be the most space-saving one, even if you only use one "application hash function" (like Murmur hash with 64 bits). You just pick the "Bloom hash functions" to be a function of this "application hash function" (64-bit Murmur hash), like so (assuming `int` is 32 bit and `long` is 64 bit):

```
long m = murmur(x)
h(x, i) = (int) (m >> 32) + i * (int) m
```

And that's actually easier *and* faster than calculating multiple "application hash functions". In a loop, that looks like this:

```
long m = murmur(x)
int hash = (int) (m >> 32);
int add = (int) m;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    ... test / set the bit depending on "hash" ...
    hash += add;
}
```

Many Bloom filter libraries do it like this, for example the Bloom filter implementation in Guava.